# Objective C - XCode not recognizing variable outside of if statement

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocos2d-iphone, scope

Trying to set a sprite filename with an if statement, then load the proper file based on that string.  It looks like there's a problem with my variable scope, but I don't know what it is.

Here's my code:

```
if ([[GameManager sharedGameManager] newHighScore] == TRUE) {
    NSString *highScoreLabelText = @"label-new-high-score.png"
} else {
    NSString *highScoreLabelText = @"label-high-score.png"
}

CCSprite *highScoreLabel = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:highScoreLabelText];
[highScoreLabel setAnchorPoint:ccp(0,0)];
[highScoreLabel setPosition:ccp(20, winSize.height * 0.575f)];
[self addChild:highScoreLabel];
```

XCode is flagging an error, saying that highScoreLabelText is an undeclared identifier, and thus won't compile the app.  Do I need to declare something else along with the NSString to get the rest of the code to work with the variable?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is because you declared two separate inner-scope variables in both branches of `if`. Neither of these two variables is visible outside its scope, so you are getting an error.

You should move the declaration out of `if`, like this:

```
NSString *highScoreLabelText;
if ([[GameManager sharedGameManager] newHighScore] == TRUE) {
    highScoreLabelText = @"label-new-high-score.png"
} else {
    highScoreLabelText = @"label-high-score.png"
}
```

Now `highScoreLabelText` is visible outside of your `if` statement.

Comment: @MyKuLLSKI Over the last few months I observed that correct answers with lots of details get more attention than simply correct answers; correct answers with code and lots of details get yet more attention. Providing the details or fixing the OP's code takes time, so you often end up posting your answer later than someone else who spotted the error at the same time as you did. I am not among the fastest typists, so I have a relative disadvantage here. When I see an answer of the comparable quality posted ahead of my answer, I delete my answer, unless I see errors in the other answer's code.

Answer (score 3):

Declare the local variable outside the if-else statement

Comment: this is correct, it is out of scope when you try to use it outside the if, declare it before with a `NSString *thisString;` and then just set the value in the if statement.